# calculate a running total between two fields in SqlServer 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Imagine the following table:

```
prprno      prprdt    pritcd     prqnty    popono      poqnty
----------  --------  --------   --------  --------    --------
2013100017  28-10-13  220010284  2000      2013100017  800
2013100017  28-10-13  220010284  2000      2013100018  500
2013100017  28-10-13  220010284  2000      2013100019  500
2013100017  28-10-13  220010284  2000      2013100020  200
```

I would like a query that returns a running total (prqnty-poqnty)

```
prprno      prprdt    pritcd     prqnty    popono      poqnty    blnce
----------  --------  --------   --------  --------    --------  ---------- 
2013100017  28-10-13  220010284  2000      2013100017  800       1200
2013100017  28-10-13  220010284  2000      2013100018  500        700
2013100017  28-10-13  220010284  2000      2013100019  500        200
2013100017  28-10-13  220010284  2000      2013100020  200          0
```

There is one purchase requisition (2013100017) with one item (220010284) & this item received against different purchase order no. (popono) and (poqnty). I want running balance this item.

select pr.prcocd, pr.prprno, prprdt, pr.pritcd, pr.pritcc, iname, iunit, prsrno, prqnty
    into #tmppr
    from fisprq10 pr
    inner join fisitem it on pr.prcocd=it.icocd and  pr.pritcd=it.icode and pr.pritcc=it.icccd
    where pr.prcocd='001'
    and pr.prprno between 2013100017 and 2013100017
    and pr.prprdt between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-31'
    order by pr.prprdt, pr.prprno, pr.prsrno

```
select po.pococd, po.popono, po.popodt, po.poprty, po.poptcc, cu.mcdesc, po.poqnty, po.poprno, po.poitcd, po.poitcc
into #tmppo
from fispod10 po
inner join fglcust cu on po.pococd=cu.mccocd and po.poprty=cu.mccode and po.poptcc=cu.mccccd 
where po.pococd='001' and cu.mccs='S' and po.poopbl<>'Y'
and po.poprno between 2013100017 and 2013100017
and po.popodt <= '2013-10-31'
order by po.poprno

select pr.prprno, max(pr.prprdt) as prprdt, pr.pritcd, pr.pritcc, max(pr.iname) as iname, max(pr.iunit) as iunit,
sum(pr.prqnty) as prqnty,
isnull(po.popono, 0) as popono, max(isnull(po.poprty, '')) as poprty, max(isnull(po.poptcc, '')) as poptcc,
max(isnull(po.mcdesc, '')) as mcdesc, sum(isnull(po.poqnty, 0)) as poqnty
from #tmppr pr
left outer join #tmppo po on pr.prprno=po.poprno and pr.pritcd=po.poitcd and pr.pritcc=po.poitcc
group by pr.prprno, pr.pritcd, pr.pritcc, po.popono
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: You mean prqnty - runningtotal(poqnty)? Just to clarify :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
;with T as(
    select *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by prprno) RNum
    From YourTable
)
select 
    prprno,   
    prprdt, 
    pritcd, 
    prqnty, 
    popono, 
    poqnty,
    prqnty-(select SUM(poqnty) from T b where b.RNum<=a.RNum) blnce
from T a
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa70d/2)

For  different `pritcd`, please check the below query.

```
;with T as(
    select *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by prprno) RNum
    From YourTable
)
select 
    prprno,   
    prprdt, 
    pritcd, 
    prqnty, 
    popono, 
    poqnty,
    prqnty-(select SUM(poqnty) from T b where b.RNum<=a.RNum and b.pritcd=a.pritcd) blnce
from T a
```

Comment: but if i have multiple pritcd (item code) and other pritcd use in another popono

Comment: @Sunny Please add such an input and expected output for a clearer view.

Comment: can u plz give me ur mail id that i will send u my real situation

Comment: Yeah sure... You can send query @ technicaldoubts@gmail.com

Comment: thsnx... i have send u email

Comment: ur awesome :)... will u plz plz plz tech me sql :)

Comment: @sunny it's quite easy pick up a couple of books on SQL server MS have quite a few out or T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can write this as a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT prprno ,prprdt ,pritcd ,prqnty , popono ,poqnty ,
    (SELECT SUM(T2.poqnty)
    FROM table1 AS T2
    WHERE T2.prprno = T1.prprno  --one purchase requisition 
    AND T2.pritcd = T1.pritcd
    AND T2.popono > t1.popono) AS blnce
FROM table1 AS T1
ORDER BY T1.popono ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 Declare @tbl table(prprno varchar(50),prprdt varchar(50),pritcd int,prqnty int,popono int,poqnty int)
insert into @tbl
select 2013100017,  '28-10-13',  220010284,  2000,      2013100017,  800
union all
select 2013100017,  '28-10-13',  220010284,  2000,      2013100018,  500
union all
select 2013100017,  '28-10-13',  220010284,  2000,      2013100019,  500
union all
select 2013100017,  '28-10-13',  220010284,  2000,      2013100020,  200

select ta.prprno,
      ta.prprdt,
      ta.pritcd,
      ta.prqnty,
      ta.popono,
      ta.poqnty, 
      isnull((select sum(poqnty) from @tbl where ta.popono < popono),0) as blnce
from @tbl ta
inner join @tbl tb on ta.prprno=tb.prprno and ta.popono=tb.popono
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try

```
select prprno,
      prprdt,
      pritcd,
      prqnty,
      popono,
      poqnty, 
      (select sum(poqnty) from tbl_a where ta.popono < popono) as blnce
from tbl_a ta
```

Comment: This wont's work as this will consider total of all purchase order no with different purchase requisition and pritcd number.